# HTML integration in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Am new in android. I have some doubt about the general features of android . Help will be appreciated :)

1. Is it possible to implement HTML design as layout in android (in XML)?
2. Is it possible to integrate JavaScript in android ?

Comment: I'm not sure, there is no possibility to design android layout using HTML and javascript. Having possibility to loading Html pages into android view. If you want to do Html and javascript in android, then go for PhoneGap Android.

Comment: OK..PhoneGap supports supports html and android but am searching it with native..thnks for the replay  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the html page in the raw resources folder, and to load it you call `loadData()` method on the webview, you need to pass it the [mimetype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), and a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Here is an example of the method call

```
webview.loadData(readTextFromResource(R.raw.help), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

You can read more at the following tutorial:

http://www.monocube.com/2011/02/08/android-tutorial-html-file-in-webview/

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is possible to implement `HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT` in android using a concept called **Webview**.

A code spinet to demonstrate how to use `WebView`

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
String url = "http://www.youtube.com";
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Demonstration for using 'WebView'

```
public class Placement extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    EditText et;
    String reg;
    Button sub;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.placement_layout);
    showResults();
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private void showResults() {
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
            Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    String url = "http://dibyaranjan.net76.net/placement.php";
    Log.d("Link", url);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    final Activity MyActivity = this;
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
            MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);
            if (progress == 100)
                MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });
}

protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Webview ok. but my query is  crate a page in HTML including tables buttons and text fields (like xml layout in android) and directly call on create ? does Webview functions like this ?

Comment: if you want to develop Android App using html/js/css, use PhoneGap, as was said

Comment: Yes. First of all you need to create an HTML page which should have all the button, tables and all... Now embed the url in place of youtube url you will see. Adding the complete code in few seconds.

Comment: wow that's cool .. one more doubt :) can we store the .html file in folder and called that particular file (like layout/index.html) ?

Comment: what about this    http://www.monocube.com/2011/02/08/android-tutorial-html-file-in-webview/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18853/discussion-between-arun-and-dibya)

Answer (score 0):

You can't hard core integrate HTML/Javascript in Android. But you can use html/javascript/css to develop Android apps using PhoneGap framework.